# How to get touchpad functional, again?

Tags: touchpad, gnome2

I messed something up and can't get my touchpad functional *at all* on GNOME 2.30 any more. I looked at Mouse Preferences on the Touchpad tab, and can't find the magic switch. The touchpad works on the Virtual Terminals, and on LXDE.

Here's output from `dmesg`, after running `sudo modprobe psmouse`:

```
[29186.004285] Synaptics Touchpad, model: 1, fw: 6.3, id: 0x9280b1, caps: 0xa04793/0x304000/0x0
[29186.004295] serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio4/input0
[29186.041853] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input22
[29191.135029] input: PS/2 Generic Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio4/serio9/input/input23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a problem with GConf.

With `gconf-editor`, reach the `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad` "folder" and make sure `touchpad_enabled` is ticked.

I've set this value as mandatory because for some reason this value kept getting disabled. This hasn't happened since.